# How I get the users of a folder in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, active-directory, ldap

hi I want to build a LDAP Query how I get all User in a under folder... For example:

```
OU=DBG,OU=THINCLIENT,OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=YourDomain,DC=com
```

I want to get all Users ins this folder from the Active Directory. For this I have a Query but I don't know how I get the users of this Folder :(

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(??????))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
string container = "OU=DBG,OU=THINCLIENT,OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=YourDomain,DC=com";
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain", container))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for UserPrincipal 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

You'll need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly in your references, and you'll need a line like this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

at the top of your code-behind file for this to work.

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.DirectoryServices Namespace.

```
 DirectoryEntry scope = new   DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=DBG,OU=THINCLIENT,OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=YourDomain,DC=com");

 string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user))";
 string[] attrs = new string[]{"samaccountname","whencreated"};
 DirectorySearcher searcher = new  DirectorySearcher(scope,filter,attrs);

 foreach(SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
 {
     //result.Properties["attribute"][0].ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(homeDirectory=*YourFolderName*))
```